# Java - UnknownHostException

Tags: java

dedicated Linux server throws UnknownHostException.

```
InetAddress addr;
    try {
        addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        throw new InstantiationError("cannot find hub ip");
    }
```

Comment: Have you had a look at these http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=getLocalHost+UnknownHostException as I believe the are multiple possible causes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you might not have mapping of `localhost`  in your `system32\drivers\etc\hosts` (win) [`/etc/hosts`](http://www.faqs.org/docs/securing/chap9sec95.html) (linux)

Answer (score 0):

Another option I found was this(which I like as I don't have to repeat the hostname in both files now)...

[java getLocalHost() UnknownHostException /etc/hosts file differs linux api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159444/java-getlocalhost-unknownhostexception-etc-hosts-file-differs-linux-api)